# What is the proper way to construct a BigInteger from an implied unsigned hexadecimal string?

Tags: c#, biginteger, hex, ones-complement

I'm running into a problem where as I have an implied unsigned hexadecimal number as a string, provided from user input, that needs to be converted into a `BigInteger`.

Thanks to the signed nature of a `BigInteger` any input where the highest order bit is set (0x8 / 1000b) the resulting number is treated as negative. This issue however can't be resolved by simply checking the sign bit and multiplying by -1 or getting the absolute value due to ones's complement which will not respect the underlying notation e.g. treating all values 0xF* as a -1.

As follows are some example input/output

```cs
var style = NumberStyles.HexNumber | NumberStyles.AllowHexSpecifier;


BigInteger.TryParse("6", style) == 6   // 0110 bin
BigInteger.TryParse("8", style) == -8  // 1000 bin
BigInteger.TryParse("9", style) == -7  // 1001 bin
BigInteger.TryParse("A", style) == -6  // 1010 bin
...
BigInteger.TryParse("F", style) == -1  // 1111 bin
...
BigInteger.TryParse("FA", style) == -6 // 1111 1010 bin
BigInteger.TryParse("FF", style) == -1 // 1111 1111 bin
...
BigInteger.TryParse("FFFF", style) == -1 // 1111 1111 1111 1111 bin
```

What is the proper way to construct a `BigInteger` from an implied unsigned hexadecimal string?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Prefixing your hex string with a "0" should do it:

```
BigInteger.TryParse(string.Format("0{0}", "FFFF"), style, ...)
```

My BigInteger is 65535 in the example above.

*Edit*

Excerpt from the BigInteger [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.numerics.biginteger(v=vs.100).aspx):

> When parsing a hexadecimal string, the BigInteger.Parse(String,
>   NumberStyles) and BigInteger.Parse(String, NumberStyles,
>   IFormatProvider) methods assume that if the most significant bit of
>   the first byte in the string is set, or if the first hexadecimal digit
>   of the string represents the lower four bits of a byte value, the
>   value is represented by using two's complement representation. For
>   example, both "FF01" and "F01" represent the decimal value -255. **To
>   differentiate positive from negative values, positive values should
>   include a leading zero.** The relevant overloads of the ToString method,
>   when they are passed the "X" format string, add a leading zero to the
>   returned hexadecimal string for positive values.

Comment: In cases where the input string is fully numeric, however a "0x" prefix is allowed. Sure, I can check for the existence of said sub string remove it and prepend a zero (actually that's what I'm doing at the moment) I'm just hoping for a more correct answer.

Comment: Updated my answer. Adding a leading zero seems like the proper technique to use.

Comment: Sure enough. Marked as correct, and slightly disappointed there isn't an existing unsigned biginteger.