# Hexadecimal on BigInteger

Tags: c#, hex

I have a string which contains a big hexadecimal number, something like this :

```cs
string hexa = "292145F2E92145E6B92FAA6A95FF7E6B92145FAA6A22DE192145FAA696043F457306A";
```

I just want to transform this `hexa` string in a `BigInteger` variable  (WITHOUT modifying the value of the string) to use it after.

Something like this :

```cs
BigInteger blabla = new BigInteger(hexa);
```

I just want the same string, but in `BigInteger` variable

Comment: Parsing `BigInteger` works just like the other integer types in C#. See duplicates. You may also want to read the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26871079/what-is-the-proper-way-to-construct-a-biginteger-from-an-implied-unsigned-hexedi)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can `BigInteger.Parse` it with `AllowHexSpecifier` flag given:

```
using System.Globalization;

...

string hexa = "292145F2E92145E6B92FAA6A95FF7E6B92145FAA6A22DE192145FAA696043F457306A";
var bigInt = BigInteger.Parse(hexa, NumberStyles.AllowHexSpecifier);
```

Answer (score 4):

Try the [`BigInteger.Parse`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.numerics.biginteger.parse?view=netcore-3.1#System_Numerics_BigInteger_Parse_System_String_System_Globalization_NumberStyles_) static method, and pass either the `NumberStyles.HexNumber` or `NumberStyles.AllowHexSpecifier` flag.